# Persist rest of the object when updating fields with $set- mongoose

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

Below is my collection structure :

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("59c9e021af4886c9149a28c7"),
    "userkey" : "r1Et2ZNdW",
    "devicekey" : "12345",
    "analog" : {
        "4" : 458,
        "6" : 448,
        "7" : 100
    },
    "__v" : 0
}
```

My update code for the collection is :

```
DeviceModel.update({_id : device.id}, {$set : {"analog" : analog}}, function(err, doc){
            if(err) throw err;
            console.log("Device switches updated");
});
```

I want to update the one (or more) value of "analog" object. I may or may not have entire value of the "analog" collection. Which means most of the time I will be having just `{"7" : 200}` or `{"6" : 500}`...etc. If I use this in my above update code it works. But the problem is rest of the items in the object will be removed. That is, the "analog" object will become just `{"7" : 200}`. What change should I do to my update code to persist the rest of the Object.? or do I need to change my entire logic ?

Comment: Have you tried { $set: { <field1>: <value1>, ... } }  ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to first flatten the `analog` variable object into another object with a property that uses the dot notation. This enables the **[`$set`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/update/set/#set-fields-in-embedded-documents)** operator to correctly update the embedded field denoted in the dot notation without updating/removing/affecting the other fields.

So, in your example you can go about this:

```
let setObject = {};
Object.keys(analog).forEach(function (key) {
    setObject[`analog.${key}`] = analog[key];
});

DeviceModel.update(
    { '_id': device.id }, 
    { '$set': setObject }, 
    function(err, doc) {
        if(err) throw err;
        console.log("Device switches updated");
    }
);
```

Comment: Works perfectly. Thanks alot. One small doubt, why did you used '' around _id & $set ?

Comment: Thanks. One more doubt, what if I have one more flatten object to update.? Like my collection have a 'digital' collection and I have the object flatten and ready as setObject2.

Comment: @JitheshKt I can't really make out your question; _my collection have a 'digital' collection_? Did you perhaps mean a "digital" field in your device collection?

Comment: I believe this warrants a new question since editing the existing answer to accommodate this is inappropriate on SO.